# Add new column using ternary condition in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, conditional-operator

How could I write this ternary condition so that I'll have a Boolean column in my data-frame.

```
partenaire['topcodeclub'] = ''
for id, i in enumerate(partenaire.Adresse):
    i = str(i)
    r1 = re.findall(r"\d{5}",i)
    'True' if (r1[0][:2]==partenaire.basecodeclub[id])  else 'False'
```

Let's say I've two columns which I compare in every iteration. If match it True else it False in my `topcodeclub` How to add `True` and `false` in that column.

Comment: I'd approach it different: `df['topcodeclub'] = np.where(partenaire['Adresse'] == partenaire['basecodeclub'],'True','False)` let me know if it works nd I'll make it an answer

Comment: The problem is it's not all the address but just the two first digits of postal code.

Comment: Ah true, I totally missed the regex in there. Would you care to share some rows of your dataframe please?

Comment: Yes `Adress` may be `RUE DU MARECHAL DE LATTRE TASSIGNY 59170 CROIX`
`basecodeclub` example `59` for a true result.

Comment: Note that "'True' if (r1[0][:2]==partenaire.basecodeclub[id])  else 'False'" should evaluate the same as "r1[0][:2]==partenaire.basecodeclub[id]"

Comment: Can't you just assign `partenaire['topcodeclub'] = 'True' if (r1[0][:2]==partenaire.basecodeclub[id])  else 'False'`. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Then how to append this these True False  in the column `topcodeclub`

Comment: @davidbilla I got False where i should got True.

Comment: To add a column: topcodeclub['match'] = <expression which produces a list of True/False values>

Comment: @abdoulsn the result might be due to the regex is str and basecodeclub is int..

Comment: That's yes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your data frame look something like this:

```
                             Address basecodeclub
0           some false address 12345           12
1  whatever other address 67890 here           45
2                and more 34567 here           43
3           and even more 54321 then           54
```

You can use `str.extract` on `Address` column and match against `basecodeclub`:

```
>>> df['Address'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})')[0].str[:2] == df['basecodeclub']

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Just assign these values to `topcodeclub`:

```
>>> df['topcodeclub'] = df['Address'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})')[0].str[:2].eq(df['basecodeclub'])
                             Address basecodeclub  topcodeclub
0           some false address 12345           12         True
1  whatever other address 67890 here           45        False
2                and more 34567 here           43        False
3           and even more 54321 then           54         True
```

In most cases there's almost always a vectorized method to accomplish what you want in `pandas`.  You should avoid looping the frame as much as possible.

Comment: I was thinking that basecodeclub was a scalar value rather than a column in the dataframe, but that should work in r.ook's code as well.

Comment: It should work but i got always False. My col `Address` is object and `basecodeclub` is int. When I extract the digits may be I've to convert them to int??

Comment: Thanks it worked I just converted the regex to int.
`partenaire['topcodeclub'] = partenaire['Adresse'].str.extract(r'(\d{5})')[0].str[:2].astype(int).eq(partenaire['basecodeclub'])`